# how do i push element in double nested array MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how to i push value in double nested array as shown in below code !!

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("627ce38702f566ef8e89977a"),
        "name" : "max",
        "sub" : {
                "type" : "maths",
                "grades" : [
                        {
                                "semOne" : [
                                        7,
                                        8,
                                        9
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                                "semTwo" : [
                                        9,
                                        11,
                                        12
                                ]
                        }
                        
                    ]
            }
    }
```

***let say i want to add 13 in semOne, how do i add ??***

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$push` in update with `arrayFilters`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("627ce38702f566ef8e89977a")
},
{
  $push: {
    "sub.grades.$[g].semOne": 13
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "g.semOne": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ub9fZqFE1Gu) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this:

```
const object = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("627ce38702f566ef8e89977a"),
    "name" : "max",
    "sub" : {
            "type" : "maths",
            "grades" : [
                    {
                            "semOne" : [
                                    7,
                                    8,
                                    9
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                            "semTwo" : [
                                    9,
                                    11,
                                    12
                            ]
                    }
                    
                ]
        }
}
```

Try this:

```
object.sub.grades[0].semOne.push(13)
```

You might have facing error that .push is not a function, because "grades" is an array and here you have to define object position to push something.

Comment: hi atul, is ther any other way using $push , asking out of curiosity !!